# Getting a migration exception when trying to create <NotMapped> property of String in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a non-mapped String property in an entity; however, the migration fails to create the migration class.  However, it works using Integer.  The following shows what I have tested:

```
Private _testProp As Integer
<NotMapped> _
Public Property TestProp() As Integer
    Get
        Return _testProp
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _testProp = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Creating the property using Integer works with both accessors:

```
PM> Add-Migration Test
Scaffolding migration 'Test'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Test' again.
```

This is the migration file, which is what I expect when adding a non-mapped property to an existing entity:

```
Namespace Migrations
    Public Partial Class Test
        Inherits DbMigration

        Public Overrides Sub Up()
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Down()
        End Sub
   End Class
End Namespace
```

However, when I add a non-mapped property using String with both accessors (*using only the get accessor actually works*), the migration fails.

```
Private _testProp As String
<NotMapped> _
Public Property TestProp() As String
    Get
        Return _testProp
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _testProp = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I get the following exception:

```
PM> Add-Migration Test
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'TestProp' is not a declared property on type 'TestEntity'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.
    at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.Configure(String structuralTypeName, IEnumerable`1 properties, IEnumerable`1 propertyPath, PrimitivePropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration)
```

Surely, this can't be a limitation of EntityFramework code first migrations?  If it isn't, what am I doing wrong?

***Update***
This is in the OnModelCreating method of the DbContext:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

    EFHelpers.StringHelper.DisableUnicodeForAllEntityStrings(Me, modelBuilder)

    TurnOnCascadeDeletes(modelBuilder)
    TurnOffCascadeDeletes(modelBuilder)
    MapTables(modelBuilder)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have had this problem for a while. But for me it works in another project. Try to create a stand-alone project and see if it works as excepted. I never figured out what caused it.

Comment: Interestingly, I created a new Vb.Net and C# code first project and it worked in both.  This causes me think that the project I'm on has configured something the in the DbContext (or somewhere else) that is causing this issue.  I still don't know what that may be though.

Comment: Did you override OnModelCreating?  If so can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out his line:
EFHelpers.StringHelper.DisableUnicodeForAllEntityStrings(Me, modelBuilder)

It is not part of the framework, happens on modelCreating, and it looks like it might do something to Strings (it's called String helper).

Comment: I commented that out and the migrations started working.  I think what the architect was trying to do was ensure only ascii was going into the database.  I'm going to suggest the following change:  modelBuilder.Properties(Of String)().Configure(Sub(p) p.IsUnicode(False))